# Google Sheets View-Only Banner Appeared for Editors

Tags: google-sheets

I'm an editor on a Google Sheet, as are a number of other people. Additionally, the sheet is publically edit-enabled for anyone with the link. However, a small green banner has appeared at the top of the sheet, and I'm trying to understand why, & what can be done about it. It says:

`The file is view-only    No edits can be made to this file. Contact file owner for details.`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It would be better if you could raise this matter with the experts [here](https://support.google.com/docs/community), as Google Sheets has a dedicated community. Upon checking [a related post](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/133307049?hl=en&msgid=145681016) there, it is possible that the owner's storage space is running out, thus causing the banner to appear on the owner's document.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this message appeared because the owner's Google Drive was out of storage. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Moving forward, for any Google Sheet-related matters that are not related to APIs, programming, formulas, etc., they should be first asked in the official community forum at [the Google Docs Editors Help Community](https://support.google.com/docs/community).